# Convert double to string

Tags: c#, typeconverter

i have three double variable a ,b  and c

```
a = 0.000006 
b = 6 
c = a/b;
```

so C should be 0.000001

i want to show this value in text box so i wrote

```
textbox.text = c.tostring();
```

but it's give result as "1E-06"..

Can anybody help me out how can i put correct value in textbox ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double to string conversion without scientific notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546113/double-to-string-conversion-without-scientific-notation)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
a = 0.000006;
b = 6;
c = a/b;

textbox.Text = c.ToString("0.000000");
```

As you requested:

```
textbox.Text = c.ToString("0.######");
```

This will only display out to the 6th decimal place if there are 6 decimals to display.

Comment: I don't want to give all time decimal mean if a= 6 / b= 2 then c should be 3 not 3.000000

Answer (score 20):

Try `c.ToString("F6");`

(For a full explanation of numeric formatting, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx))