# Formatting double to String

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I make such formatting:

```
 str += String.Format("{0,-25}", doubl);
```

I need my numbers to be divided by spaces, that's why I use {0,-25}.

But sometimes I get numbers like 2.15083096934631E-05

How to get traditional numbers like 0,000021508 , without "E-05" ?

The value of doubl is like 0.000021436573129839587

Comment: 2.15083096934631E-05 is 0.0000215, you know?

Comment: 2.15083096934631E-05 is not 2.1508309. it's ~ 0,000021508309

Comment: 0,000021508309 - I agree. But how to show it in this way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546113/double-to-string-conversion-without-scientific-notation

Answer (score 2):

Use the [The "0" Custom Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#Specifier0):

```
str = doubl1.ToString("0.0000000");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `double.ToString("format")` (F - Fixed-point)

```
str=doubleValue.ToString("F10");
```

Comment: [F - Fixed point and 10 - number of decimal digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can format the output by passing in `F` or `N` to the `ToString()`, to represent more decimal points i think you will have to specify something like `N15` (find the suitable limit you need depending on your values) but the issue here is trailing `0` after your actual number

```
[double value].ToString("N15") // this should output without the exponent sign
```

To avoid trailing zeros you just need to Trim

```
[double value].ToString("N15").TrimEnd('0');
```

Answer (score 0):

All the Answers prior to mine were fine but for me, I had a very ugly problem. My 'Answer' would be filled by Zero's and it made the answer very bulky if there was only 5 Zeros needed. I came up with this:

```
double Q = ((1000 * 1000) * (2 * 2));
double Answer = ((Q * 199) / 2);
this.AnswerTBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:F" + Answer.ToString().Length + "}", Answer);
```

This tidy's up the 'Uglyness' of unnecessary Zeros.

All the Best

Chris