# Double ToString() no scientific notation not returning a string for 0.0

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I need to return the string representation of a double in decimal notation rather than scientific and I used a modified version of the accepted solution here:

[Double ToString - No Scientific Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964737/double-tostring-no-scientific-notation)

```
private static readonly string format = "." + new string('#', 324);
foo.ToString(format);
```

This works well other than for a value that equals zero i.e. 0, 0.0, 0.000 etc where it returns an empty string.

What would be the easiest way to return a string representing 0 for any value of zero.

I don't mind if the string is 0 or 0.0 etc as long as it is numerical and not scientific.

Edit: I know I could add a conditional statement to check if the string is empty but I am interested to see if there is a way to do it using string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You could always add a statement like:

```
foo.ToString(format)

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(foo))
foo = "0";
```

Comment: I know that and it's a good answer so you get an uptvote but I was hoping there is a less hacky way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  string format = "0." + new string('#', 324);
```

It will add zero before dot (if needed)

See example [ideone](http://ideone.com/reC5aV)

Comment: Thanks but I tried that also. For the first one I would have liked it to return "0.9". The second one is basically exactly what I did as the double value was 0.0 and it returned an empty string. SO I removed the # in "#." as it made no difference. Probably should have put that in the original question though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's what you are looking for:

```
        double aa = 12.33333;

        string foo = String.Format("{0:0.#}", System.Convert.ToSingle(aa));
```

Comment: I haven't but as that is just a wrapper for yourDouble.ToString() I imagine it would return the same as just calling ToString() on the double? So it would return a 0 for ToString but then I cannot format it to not use scientific notation for large decimals.

Comment: Why convert to `Single` (i.e. `float`)?

Answer (score 0):

Argh, those hacks people use. To give one hack more here:

```
foo.ToString(format + ";" + "-" + format + ";" + "0");
```

or with

```
static readonly string newFormat = format + ";" + "-" + format + ";" + "0";
```

defined *under* `format` in the code source, just:

```
foo.ToString(newFormat);
```

Of course that is a constant, so it is really:

```
foo.ToString(.####################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################;-.####################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################;0);
```

Hope you like it (I don't).