# Prevent C# from using 'E+x' with large numbers

Tags: c#, .net

I've created a small program that takes a scientific notation value (i.e. 1x10^10), and displays its full value (I'm practising parameter passing by the way, hence why I created a separate subroutine):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a scientific notation number: ");
        string num = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write(ConvertString(num));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static double ConvertString(string num)
    {           
        string[] Array = num.Split('x');
        string[] Array2 = Array[1].Split('^');

        double multiplier = (Convert.ToDouble(Array[0]));
        double value = (Convert.ToDouble(Array2[0]));
        double power = (Convert.ToDouble(Array2[1]));

        double conversion = multiplier * Math.Pow(value, power);
        return conversion;         
    }
```

It works fine when 'power' is less than 15. However, when it's greater than or equal to 15, the console displays 'E+x' (where 'x' is 'power') instead of the full value. For example:

```
1x10^5: 100000
1x10^10: 10000000000
1x10^15: 1E+15
```

This is the same case for negative powers as well. When 'power' is greater than or equal to -5, it displays 'E-x' instead:

```
1x10^-1: 0.1
1x10^-2: 0.01
1x10^-5: 1E-05
```

Is there any way to prevent this?
Thanks.

Comment: There is also an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964737/double-tostring-no-scientific-notation

Comment: `System.Double` is only accurate to 15 places, try using `System.Decimal`

Comment: This worked very well: `Convert.ToDecimal(doubleValue).ToString()`. Thanks for pointing me to it... I wouldn't have written all this if I found that beforehand! :D

Comment: @ZephyrLM No problem, be careful because the range is smaller `(-7.9 x 10^28 to 7.9 x 10^28) / (10^0 to 10^28)`

Comment: My maximum range would be around 10^23 anyway, so all is well.