# Display double value without scientific notation

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have a null able double value which get values from data base.It retrieve value from data base as '1E-08'. I want to display the value with out scientific notification (0.00000001)

I used the following code.

```
double? valueFromDB=1E-08;
string doubleValue=valueFromDB.Value.Value.ToString();
string formatedString=String.Format("{0:N30}", doubleValue);
```

But the value of formatedString is still 1E-08.

Comment: `doubleValue` is a string not a double, so use `String.Format("{0:N30}", valueFromDB.Value)`.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546113/double-to-string-conversion-without-scientific-notation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `string.Format` *with a string*. That's not going to apply numeric formatting. Try removing the second line:

```
double? valueFromDB = 1E-08;
string formattedString = String.Format("{0:N30}", valueFromDB.Value);
```

Or alternatively, specify the format string in a call to `ToString` on the value:

```
double? valueFromDB = 1E-08;
string formattedString = valueFromDB.Value.ToString("N30");
```

That produces `0.000000010000000000000000000000` for me.