# What is the correct datatype for very large numerical values and how is it used?

Tags: c#, factorial

I am dealing with a question from hackerrank. I am not able to display correct output i don't know which data type to use in this program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution 
{
    static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        double n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        double factorial = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            factorial *= i;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(factorial);
    }
}
```

I am getting this output

```
        1.5511210043331E+25
```

But Expected output is

```
        15511210043330985984000000
```

I am thinking to use long but i don't know how. Please suggest me how to deal with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you use `BigInteger` instead of `double`. It's unclear why your question title talks about `long` but you're actually using `double`...

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I thought long will have more capability than double

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double to string conversion without scientific notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546113/double-to-string-conversion-without-scientific-notation)

Comment: Well you haven't shown us any *attempt* to use `long`. What have you tried? (But really, `BigInteger` is a better solution here - factorial will go out of the range of `long` pretty quickly.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Based on his example. I'd say he's already out of the range of long.

Comment: i used biginteger and ran the program . but my output is "15511210043330986055303168". It is different from expected output. Any suggestions

Comment: That means your solution did not solve the problem you were trying to solve. It has nothing to do with the data type you used. BigInteger is the correct type. Your question has been answered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As someone suggested in the comments, using BigInteger is also a good idea.

Here is documentation on BigInteger:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx

**BigInteger Solution:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics; // This is important

class Solution 
{
    static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // No reason to accept a double here

        BigInteger factorial = 1; 

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            factorial *= i;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(factorial.ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Not working . Getting this output "7034535277573963776"

Comment: I added another solution using a better approach. Try that.

Comment: Its working . why did you use tostring . it is working without that