# Convert Double to String (The complete number) C#

Tags: c#, string, formatting, double, number-formatting

I want to do a **Double** to **String** conversion, but there's a problem.
If I convert a Double to a String with the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double dou = 1000000000000000000;
    // Result dou = 1E+18
    string str = dou.ToString();
    // Again Result str = 1E+18
}
```

I need the result to be `str = 1000000000000000000`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Might this be C#? Please explicitly mention what programming language this is supposed to be!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Double to string conversion without scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1546113/3744182), agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
decimal dec = (decimal)dou;
string str = dec.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it C#?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-numeric-n-format-specifier
Try play with:

```
dou.ToString("N")
```

Comment: this Result = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000.00. I need **only** result = 1000000000000000000