# Converting Long String to Double in C#

Tags: c#, casting

I have the following code to convert a very long numeric string.

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    string longString = "1000000000000000000000000000001";
    double convertedString = Double.Parse(test);
    Console.WriteLine(test2);
  }
}
```

However, convertedString is outputted in scientific notation:

```
1E+30
```

Is there a way to retain the exact value of the double when I convert it from a string?

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33697376/9534819)

Comment: i'm guessing you are losing double precision with a number that big.  use a different data type.

Comment: Use Big INT Class.

Comment: That value can't be stored exactly in a double.

Comment: @jdweng I guess you mean the [BigInteger struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: The Bigint Library Class.  Converting to a double looses least significant digits.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks for the comment. I took a hard look at what I was doing and what you wrote makes the most sense. I redid my approach so as to avoid casting a string to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the output and the precision of the variable itself have nothing to do with each other. You can get the format you want by changing the [format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings), e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:N}", test1);
```

As for the precision of the variable, you should be aware that [floating point numbers are not precise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-imprecise). And your number is about ten digits too long to fit into a `long`.

You will either need to store that number as a custom data type or, if it is just an identifier and not actually a number on which you need to perform math, simply store it as a string.