# How do I write a small number to the console without the e notation in C#?

Tags: c#, scientific-notation

When I try to display a very small or a very big number, it shows us the number with the e notation.
How do I bypass this issue?

Things I have tried:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Double.Parse("1E-10", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float));
/* System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
 *     at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
 *     at Rextester.Program.Main(String[] args)
 */
```

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Math.Pow(10,-10)));
// returns 1E-10
```

```cs
double num = Math.Pow(10,-10);
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
// returns 1E-10
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546113/double-to-string-conversion-without-scientific-notation

Comment: I am not sure why this is getting upvoted. There are a million duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this one you need to use a string format. For your case `Pow(10, -10)` will return 0.0000000001, so you will need to use a format that can display 10 decimal places.

You may declare a string format like this:

```
const string format = "0.##########";
```

Then use: `Console.WriteLine(num.ToString(format));`