# C# - Double to String retuns unknown value

Tags: c#, double

Here is my c# codes :

```
double amount_dbl = double.Parse("0.00001167");
string amount_str = amount_dbl.ToString();
```

amount_str is `1.167E-05`
How can i get `0.00001167` after ToString()?

Comment: Try ToString("D") to specify the format

Comment: Define the format you want in the call to ToString. There is an overload for that.Be aware that the way you convert here is culture dependent. It may result in something unexpected on systems with a different culture setting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double to string conversion without scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546113/double-to-string-conversion-without-scientific-notation)