# Converting Decimal to string with non-default format

Tags: c#, decimal

I need to convert decimal to string, in this rulers:

```
120.00 - "120"
120.01 - "120.01"
120.50 - "120.50"
```

Comment: decimal d = 120.10m; string ds = d.ToString("0.00").Replace(".00", string.Empty); any other cases ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the [`decimal.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tostring.aspx) override to specify a formatting.

```
decimal amount = 120.00m;
string str = amount.ToString("0.00");
```

This can also be used when using `String.Format`.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", amount);
```

In the case of your first rule, it cannot be done on one line.

```
decimal amount = 120.00m;
string str = amount.ToString("0.00").Replace(".00", String.Empty);
```

Comment: but if amount 120.10m => 120.1 and it's bad

Comment: I also wrote a commentary, no other options?

Comment: @user1046047 check out my answer. I specify the overloads that you can pick

Comment: I get `cannot convert from double to string` when I try to use `decimal amount = 120.60m; string str = amount.ToString("0.00");`  Found out I needed to use `amount.ToString("F6");`. In my case I needed 6 placevalues, but I don't think it was the number of decimal points that was the problem because it complained if I did `string str = amount.ToString("0.00");` or `string str = amount.ToString("0.000000");`  I was using a `numeric` database field, which was stored using a `decimal` object. Ran across this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533931/convert-double-to-string - which helped me.

Answer (score 8):

There are different overloads for `decimal.ToString` based on what formatting you want.

**Example**

```
decimal d = 5.00
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("C")); // for currency
```

See below for other overloads... `specifier` is what you put into the `ToString(specifier)`

[MSDN Documentation on Decimal.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Decimal_ToString_System_String_)

decimal value = 16325.62m;
string specifier;

```
// Use standard numeric format specifiers.
specifier = "G";
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", specifier, value.ToString(specifier));
// Displays:    G: 16325.62
specifier = "C";
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", specifier, value.ToString(specifier));
// Displays:    C: $16,325.62
specifier = "E04";
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", specifier, value.ToString(specifier));
// Displays:    E04: 1.6326E+004
specifier = "F";
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", specifier, value.ToString(specifier));
// Displays:    F: 16325.62
specifier = "N";
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", specifier, value.ToString(specifier));
// Displays:    N: 16,325.62
specifier = "P";
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", specifier, (value/10000).ToString(specifier));
// Displays:    P: 163.26 %

// Use custom numeric format specifiers.
specifier = "0,0.000";
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", specifier, value.ToString(specifier));
// Displays:    0,0.000: 16,325.620
specifier = "#,#.00#;(#,#.00#)";
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", specifier, (value*-1).ToString(specifier));
// Displays:    #,#.00#;(#,#.00#): (16,325.62)
```

Comment: Ex. `d.ToString("F6");` will give `5.000000` - which is what helped me to write out a decimal from a `numeric` field in the database to string.  `d.ToString("0.00");` gave me  `cannot convert from double to string`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533931/convert-double-to-string

Answer (score 2):

You can use `decimal.Tostring()` method

pls go through this link  for [more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b22a4x2.aspx)

Comment: this has weird behavior though. It prints `5.00` as just `5`, which is undesirable in currency display

Answer (score 1):

Use, [decimal.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tostring.aspx) method. You can specify format with that method if you need:

```
decimal d = 120.00;
string ds = d.ToString("#,#.00#");
// ds is a formated string of d's value
```