# decimal/money in formatted string

Tags: c#, decimal, format-string

I can't format decimal in custom formatted string

```
0.656 => 0.67; 
23.656 => 23.67;
5105.54 => 5 105.54;
1234567,89 => 1 234 567,89
```

I found several posts:

[c# - Using String Format to show decimal upto 2 places or simple integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-upto-2-places-or-simple-integer)

[c# - Converting Decimal to string with non-default format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125492/converting-decimal-to-string-with-non-default-format)

but when try to use them getting several problem

for example:
on value

0.656 i'm getting ".656" or ".66"

23.656 => " 23.656" or " 23.66"

Car someone recommend links where I can find formatstring rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you actually want to convert `0.656` to `0.67`, cause it is just wrong. I guess you mean it should display as `0.66`

Use

```
YourNumber.ToString("0.##");
```

If you really want to have spaces (which again i think it is wrong):

```
YourNumber.ToString("#,##0.##").Replace("."," ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a good read:

[Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can use `String.Format` or `ToString()` overloades to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format a number as a currency value, use this

```
var d = 0.656;
Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", d); // prints "€ 0,66", in my case
```

Make sure your localization settings give you the correct currency symbol and decimal character, I.E. a point or a comma.