# Get string from large double value(C#)

Tags: c#, double, tostring

Can't find simple way to convert double to string. I need to convert large numbers without distortion. Such as:

```
double d = 11111111111111111111;
string s = d.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(s);
//1.11111111111111E+19
```

How to get string value from double value exactly the same as user enter.

`11111111111111111111111 => "11111111111111111111111"`

`1.111111111111111111111 => "1.111111111111111111111"`

Any ideas how it can be done?

Comment: If you want a string, store user input as string.

Comment: just `.ToString()`?

Comment: If you want a value that is [exactly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/11683) what the user entered, `double` is not your choice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert double to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533931/convert-double-to-string)

Comment: `.ToString()` is not working correctly with large numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double to string conversion without scientific notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546113/double-to-string-conversion-without-scientific-notation)

Comment: have a look at [this dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wjfqeo)

Comment: Having tested, this is very interesting - the number is so large that the compiler (at least in .NET Fiddle) will turn it into scientific notation in memory, causing even a literal string version to turn into `11111111111111100000`

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre This is how floating point numbers are stored in principle. It is not about how big the number is. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/11683.

Comment: In your example, you're not using any decimals. If you only need to support whole numbers, you might want to consider using [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) is a floating point type. So it has a limited accuracy. In your example, you could do something like this:

```
double d = 11111111111111111111;
string s = d.ToString("F0");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

But as you'll see,this would output `11111111111111100000` instead of `11111111111111111111`,so it has lost accuracy in the process. So the answer here is **use the right type for the work**. If you need a string, use a string variable to store the value.

**Edit**

[This was the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)  i was trying to find that explains the problem with floating point math., thanks to @GSerg

Comment: Which type I can use instead?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to achive. You have not told us anything about the process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I realized what the problem is. The double has only fifteen digits and all the rest its trash or zeros or exponentiation.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: `11111111111111111111111` is to large for a double value and also this value: `1.111111111111111111111` since the double max decimal length is 17.

> By default, a Double value contains 15 decimal digits of precision,
>   although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally.

For this reason you should use `BigInteger` and then `ToString` for formatting the output.
There is also a library in the nuget Directory called [BigRational](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BigRationalLibrary/), never used and seems in Beta stage but probably will help in solving this problem.

Comment: What about double values?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no equivalent of BigDouble in C# so you must manage yourself the decimal part.

Answer (score 1):

In *general case*, you can't do this: user can well input, say `123`, in *many a way*:

- `123`
- `123.00`
- `1.23e2`
- `12.3E1`
- `123.0e+00`
- `1230e-1`

etc. When you convert the user input into `double` you loose the initial format:

```
string userInput = ...

// double is just 123.0 whatever input has been
double value = double.Parse(userInput);
```

In case you want to *drop exponent* if it's possible you can

```
double value = 11111111111111111111;

string result = value.ToString("#######################");
```

And, please, notice, that `double` has **64 bit** to store the value, that's why a distortion is inevitable for *large numbers*:

```
// possible double, which will be rounded up
double big = 123456789123456789123456789.0;

// 1.2345678912345679E+26
Console.WriteLine(big.ToString("R"));
// 123456789123457000000000000
Console.WriteLine(big.ToString("###########################"));
```

May be you want `BigInteger` instead of `double`:

```
using System.Numerics;

...

BigInteger value = BigInteger.Parse("111111111111111111111111111111111"); 

// 111111111111111111111111111111111
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
```